# Image in Semantic UI not working in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, semantic-ui-react

I have included this already in my index.html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css"></link>
```

Still no images are displayed.I have for example tech.png in my src folder which contains Sample.js and index.js files.

Here is my Sample.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


export default class Sample extends React.Component {
 render(){
   return(
    <Image src='./src/tech.png' href as={Link} to="/Users"/>
   );

 }
```

Help me to render the image.

Comment: You have just the CSS in CDN, has the semantic library been installed since **Image** is a component?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Image is not rendered.Semantic-ui is installed

Comment: can you try the full path instead of `./src/tech.png`?

Comment: btw you don't need `href` when using `as={Link}`

Comment: <Image src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\React Playground\react\src\tech.png" /> Still didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be a CSS issue. If the CSS was not installed, the markup would still render an `img` tag with the correct source to display the image. I think what is probably happening is your image is not actually getting included in the build when Webpack runs. By default the `/src` folder is not getting automatically included into any builds in `create-react-app`.

For the image to be included you must `require()` like this:

```
<Image
  as={Link}
  src={require('./src/tech.png')}
  to='/Users'
/>
```

That will allow you to reference your image relative to your React component. This isn't an issue with `semantic-ui-react`.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about this too, as the image link of an example in the semantic ui docs looked similiar to yours:

```js
const ImageExampleImage = () => (
  <Image src='/images/wireframe/image.png' size='small' />
)
```

So I looked the example up on their GitHub, turns out if you want to link to images like that, you have to put them in the public directory of your create-react-app project, then it works.